# JRuby Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500m

Tags: jvm, jruby

I was running a JRuby `something.rb` script and suddenly it throws this:

```
Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500m.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace
```

What caused this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running out of memory (heap) reserved for Java virtual machine. Try to increase it in server startup with command line parameters or configuration files.

Something like this:

```
server_start_command -J-Xm900m
```

Or fix your ruby script to use less heap memory.

Answer (score 4):

That would be -J-Xmx900m, which is basically just passing the -Xmx flag to the underlying JVM.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run like jruby -J-Xm900m abc.rb