# what do these ruby warnings mean?

Tags: ruby, warnings, jruby

```
cqq.rb:96 **warning: Statement not reached.**

/root/newpackage/lib.rb:727 **warning: instance variable @object not initialized**

Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500m.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Exception trace follows:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

curiosu to know what these 2 mean

cqq.rb:96 **warning: Statement not reached.**

/root/newpackage/lib.rb:727 **warning: instance variable @object not initialized**

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post the code that is causing your problems.  If it's part of a huge app, try extract the problem code into a sample script (this process might also help your own investigation).

Comment: Also, why post the third error if it's not what you're asking about?  Have you tried fixing the heap space error and seeing if maybe your other errors go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning is usually due to some code never being reachable (at least in compiled languages) though it's hard to say without seeing the code around line 96 in cqq.rb.

The second warning is likely due to the error you get saying that you are out of memory and unable to allocate the necessary memory to instantiate a new object.

As for solving the second, just linking to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758374/error-your-application-used-more-memory-than-the-safety-cap-of-500m-specify-j) about that yesterday in case someone finds this question looking for a solution.