# Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500M

Tags: jvm, jruby

My question similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758374/error-your-application-used-more-memory-than-the-safety-cap-of-500m-specify-j); however, I tried the solutions proposed and I don't know what is the problem.

One of the solution was to use the following command

```
server_start_command -J-Xm900m
```

when I tried it I got command not found and I searched how to get it but couldn't find it!

I tried also this solution

```
jruby -J-Xm900m abc.rb
```

but I keep getting the same error,

```
Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 500M.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: without the content of your application, hard to tell what is going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your invocation of jruby:

You used `jruby -J-Xm900m abc.rb` but you should write `jruby -J-Xmx900m abc.rb`